# Python fill list up to certain number

Tags: python

I have a list like so: `[1,2,3,4]`

I want to fill it up to let's say `10` items, the rest with `NA`

resulting in `[1,2,3,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA]`

I could loop through it and `append` using a `if` statement. I was wondering if anybody had a way that is really short (least number of characters in code)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code golf (OP says least number of characters in code) and might be more appropriate at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: ha. didn't know that existed. you coders are hilarious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `x` is your list:

```
x += ['NA'] * (10 - len(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an efficient way to do this

```
from itertools import repeat, islice, chain
print list(islice(chain([1, 2, 3, 4], repeat("NA")), 10))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA']
```

This would work even if your actual data isn't a list but any iterable.